# Fast way of exporting the same figure n-times

Tags: matlab, export, figure

I am trying to put together an animation in matlab. For this i am showing pictures containing a description of whats currently happening in the animation. So i am writing out pictures of my figures and later on put these together to an avi file again using matlab. For the description parts to "show up" long enough i use a simple loop in which the current figure is saved n-times. Unfortunatelly this process, though matlab does not have to calculate anything new, is the slowest one.
As the loop i use the following (h_f being the figure handle):

```
for delay = 1:80 
export_fig (h_f,['-r' num2str(resolution)], ['C:\Users\Folder\Name_', '_' num2str(7700+delay) '.png']) 
end
```

I just want to ask if there is any faster way. right now it kind of feels like matlab replots the fig each time before exporting it. So is there a way of plotting the figure once and simultaneously export it n-times?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are all really identical, then you can just copy the first file into the subsequent files. Your time will be limited by the speed of your disk drive and the size of your image files.

```
% Define some of the flags as variables. This'll make it clearer
% what you're doing when you revisit the code in a year.

% Flag for the resolution
resFlag = sprintf('-r%u', resolutions);

% Base folder
folder = 'C:\Users\Folder\';

% First file number
startnum = 7701;

% This is the pattern all the filenames will use
nameToken = 'Name_%u.png';

% First filename
firstFile = fullfile(folder, sprintf(nameToken, startnum));

% Export the first file
export_fig(h_f, resFlag, firstFile);

numCopies = 80;

% Copy the file
for delay = 2:numCopies 
    % Make a new filename
    currentFile = fullfile(folder, sprintf(nameToken, startnum + delay));

    % Copy the first file into the current filename.
    copyfile(firstFile, currentFile);
end
```

Comment: thanks so much, that really saves me quite some time! :)